# How do I load optional css tags using ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

I'm trying to load optional, page-specific stylesheets using Node.js/ Express.js routing, but am having trouble with the `ejs` portion:

Express:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Home', css: 'index'}); // some pages won't have the 'css' parameter.
```

EJS loading:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/stylesheets/shared.css' />
<% if (css) { %>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/stylesheets/<%- css %>.css' />
<% } %>
```

Looking at the official [EJS documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs), my if statement follows their logic:

```
<% if (user) { %>
  <h2><%= user.name %></h2>
<% } %>
```

I am receiving the error `css is not defined`. By that logic, wouldn't the example given on the ejs website also result in an error, if `user` was not defined?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending all your data in a sub-object like this:

Express:

```
res.render('index', {data:{title:'Home',css:'index'}});
```

or

```
res.render('index', {data:{title:'Home'}});
```

EJS:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/stylesheets/shared.css' />
<% if (data.css) { %>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/stylesheets/<%- data.css %>.css' />
<% } %>
```

---

If you just send in, optionally on object like this: `{title:'Home',css:'index'}` or `{title:'Home'}` then the variable `css` may or may not be defined.

You could change your check to `if (typeof css !== 'undefined')` but I find it easier and smaller to just use a sub-object.